# asp.net td column alignment changing when hiding column

Tags: asp.net

I wan to hide and show columns based on the drop down selection. I given specific id for each `<td>`. Based on selection change columns hiding but the aliment of columns are changing. Please find the below given screen shots.

> **java script**

```
  function producttype_selection_change() {
        try {
            var type = cmbProdectType.GetText();
            if (type == "--Select--") {
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (type == "Seals") {
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }
            if (type == "Seals ,Systems & Couplings") {
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_seal_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_system_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_coupling_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_lbl.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=td_bearings_cmb.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

> **design code**

[image]

```
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="lblProductType" runat="server" Text="*Product Type :" ForeColor="Black"
            Width="90px"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left" colspan="7">
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbProdectType" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cmbProdectType"
            Width="180px" IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
            <Items>
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" Selected="true" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Seals" Value="1" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Systems" Value="2" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Couplings" Value="3" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Bearings" Value="4" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Seals & System" Value="5" />
                <dx:ListEditItem Text="Seals ,Systems & Couplings" Value="6" />
            </Items>
            <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s,e){producttype_selection_change();}" />
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" id="td_seal_lbl" runat="server" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblseals" runat="server" Text="Seals :" ForeColor="Black" Width="40px"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="td_seal_cmb" runat="server" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbSeals" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cmbSeals" Width="80px"
            IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
    <td align="right" id="td_system_lbl" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblsystem" runat="server" Text="Systems :" ForeColor="Black" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="td_system_cmb" runat="server">
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbSystems" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cmbSystems" Width="80px"
            IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
    <td align="right" id="td_coupling_lbl" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblcoupling" runat="server" Text="Couplings :" ForeColor="Black" Width="65px"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="td_coupling_cmb" runat="server">
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbCouplings" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cmbCouplings"
            Width="80px" IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
    <td align="right" id="td_bearings_lbl" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblbearings" runat="server" Text="Bearings :" ForeColor="Black" Width="60px"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="td_bearings_cmb" runat="server">
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbBearings" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="cmbBearings"
            Width="80px" IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> **current output**

[image]

> **expecting output**

[image]

Comment: Don't hide table cells with CSS, it will lead to weird results (as you have noticed). Hide the content inside the cells.

Comment: @VDWWD If I am hiding the content blank space showing on the design. For example if I select Seals and Coupling from the drop-down  , it is showing and balance columns hiding but in between seal and coupling showing extra space. Because of this this issue I tried to hide td

Comment: Then fix that with CSS and the padding/margin of the cells and their content rather than hiding the cells itself.

Answer (score 1):

Define the second `tr` row in a new table. This way, removing its cells based on different conditions does not change your layout